# How to correctly organize multiple examples on a dart package

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dart-packages

Given a dart package organized as follow

```
/example
|_______/foo
|________________/pubspec.yaml (and stuff)
|________________/main.dart
|_______/baz
|________________/pubspec.yaml (and stuff)
|________________/main.dart
/lib
|_______/foo
|________________/foo.dart
|_______/baz
|________________/baz.dart
/test
|_______/foo
|________________/foo_test.dart
|_______/baz
|________________/baz_test.dart
```

but pub.dev gives me

```
0/10 points: Package has an example
> No example found.
See package layout guidelines on how to add an example.
```

but I didn't find the [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout#examples) very helpful concerning my case

which brings me to the question in the title:

`How to correctly organize multiple examples on a dart package`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a README.md file inside your example folder, as flutter_mobx package.

look: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobx/example

Comment: works great if I have a SINGLE example, but in my case I have MULTIPLE examples, what then?

Comment: In the case of multiple dart files, you can add a README.md into example folder, as package flutter_mobx, look: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobx/example

Comment: awesome, that is what I was looking for!
edit your initial question and I'll accept it straight away